# Unable to write to process memory

Tags: winapi, shared-memory, createprocess

I am trying to fix a problem in code I am not familiar with. I have traced it down to  call to WriteProcessMemory always failing with `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS`. I have no idea why it fails.I tried to check if my process has the required access to write to its child process using `VirtualQUery` and it does. Can anyone shed some light on this? The code path is extremely convoluted so I have skipped a lot of it. Please let me know if left out any info.

```
CreateProcessAsUserW(hToken, exe, cmd_line, 
NULL, // No security attribute.
NULL, // No thread attribute.
false, // do not inherit handles
CREATE_SUSPENDED | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT | DETACHED_PROCESS | EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT | CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB, // start suspended, extended startup info, break out of job
NULL, // Use the environment of the caller
NULL, // Use current directory of the caller.
&si, 
&pi);

/*
 ....lots of work here
*/

void* address = {...};
void* var = address;   // note this line

SIZE_T written;
if(!WriteProcessMemory( pi.handle, 
var, address,  // not completely sure what it is doing here - writing contents of address to address of var?
size, &written))
{
    DWORD error = GetLastError();     // ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION buffer;
    SIZE_T num = VirtualQuery(address,&buffer,sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION));
    if(num > 0)
    {
        DWORD access = buffer.AllocationProtect;  // PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY
        DWORD state = buffer.State; // MEM_COMMIT
        DWORD type = buffer.Type;
    }
}
```

This is a 32-bit process running on 64-bit Win7.

Comment: It _looks_ like it's attempting to copy data from a process to an identical process, assuming the struct will be at the same address. With [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) that is not necessarily true on newer operating systems, even if it's starting a new process from the same binary.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ASLR is disabled for the process `/DYNAMICBASE:NO`

Comment: You should give more informations on what's the intents and context. In particular, what is really the void* address = {...}

Answer (score 0):

You're performing a local VirtualQuery before trying to write into another process, whose address space may be wildly different.

If you want to be sure to have a valid pointer in that process's adress space, either you find where that process puts what interests you (good luck with ASLR), or you allocate some memory for you within that process (with, say VirtualAllocEx()).

Note: If you actually want shared memory, you should use CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) instead.

Comment: I am performing `VirtualQuery` _after_ `WriteProcessMemory` fails just to verify if I actually have required access level. I can remove that without making any difference. I am also quite surprised that address is actually allocated locally. Are you saying it is guaranteed to fail? Even if the process being written to is identical so that the struct is at the same address? Apparently, this code was working till a few days ago.

Comment: Reread the answser. Your VirtualQuery is local to YOUR process, not the one you try to write to.

Comment: Ok. Got it. That was stupid of me. So how do I check what level of access I have to write to that process. Obviously, I don't have enough as write is failing.

Comment: @341008 I think that an access right problem would not give you ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS... Use VirtualQueryEx to check the memory in the other process